# How to present video with sound "note video autoplay done but not working sound"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make video player with an autoplay but sound is not working.

Currently I'm using this but it doesn't work as expected:

```js
var myaudio = document.getElementById("audioID");

function play() {
   return myaudio.play();
}

function stop() {
   return myaudio.pause();
}
```

```html
<video width="260" height="180" controls muted id="audioID" autoplay volume="10">
   <source src="{{ asset('video/laberspecicebymujb.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="{{ asset('video/laberspecicebymujb.ogg') }}" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has new policies regarding autoplay.
you **CAN'T** enable both autoplay and sound on chrome browsers

Comment: Absolutely right and it makes sence when you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding volume, you need to set the volume on the `onloadstart` event like below:

```
<video onloadstart="this.volume=0.2" ...>
```